# Installing mysql2 0.4.10 with native extensions Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, mysql2

I have installed rbenv to use  ruby 2.2.4  version

when I run the command `bundle install`

I get this

[image]

Why it is

```
 current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/ext/mysql2
```

as, I am using ruby 2.2.4

**is this the reason to failed to build gem native extensions?**

if, how I can fix this path?.

Comment: This seems like an incompability with your systems openssl version and the openssl required by that gem in that specific ruby version.

Comment: @cesartalves is there any way I can fix this problem, please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this error while running bundle for mysql2 (0.5.2)

Running these commands worked for me.

```
brew install openssl

bundle config --global build.mysql2 --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"

bundle
```

You can refer to this link for further help https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1005

Answer (score 0):

```
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
```

without the `cppflags` part  solve the problem.